# Repair corrupted keyring

Tags: apt, re-installation, keyrings

I believe I have corrupted all of my keyrings while trying to add keyrings for extra repositories. I foolishly moved some keyring files around in a console, and now my system is in a state such that apt-get and Ubuntu Software Center don't work any more. Ubuntu Software Center displays the following error message when trying to update packages:

> **Could not calculate the upgrade**
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and
>   include the following error message: 'E:Error,
>   pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by
>   held packages.'

Is there something I can do to repair my keyrings? Alternatively, if I absolutely have to just reinstall everything, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i understand that right or no,but upon what i understand that while you was importing new ppa or repos you mess up with your old one.so that [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html) may be solve your problem

Comment: Why would I want the Launchpad keys?

Comment: i was trying to help man as i said before "i dont know if i understand that right or no,but upon what i understand"